# Shopping context modelling

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, modeling, cqrs

I want to write my first application (e-commerce) in a DDD manner and I'd like to know whether I'm getting everything right so I want your opinion on my modelling - how can it be improved, what should I look for etc. Every feedback will be greatly appreciated.

I've divided my application into several bounded contexts (catalog, shopping, ordering) and below example is based on the shopping one. I am trying to use CQRS as well (thus `AddProductToCart` command).

My business requirements are as follows:

- Customer should be able to add product to his cart
- Price for added product should be specific to user and is based on several factors: (global discounts, user discounts and customer country (some countries have lowered base prices)

I've recognised following actors (please note comments on methods and classes):

```php
/**
 * A customer (Aggregate Root) having an unique cart
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $customerId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @var PriceProvider
     */
    private $priceProvider;

    /**
     * Adds product to customers cart with user-specific price
     *
     * @param $productId
     * @return CartLine
     */
    public function addProductToCart($productId)
    {
        $price = $this->priceProvider->priceForProduct($productId, $this->customerId, $this->country);
        return $this->cart->addLine($productId, $price);
    }
}

/**
 * Simple CartLine object for persisting purposes
 */
class CartLine
{
    public $productId;
    public $price;
    public $cartId;

    function __construct($cartId, $productId, $price)
    {
        $this->cartId    = $cartId;
        $this->price     = $price;
        $this->productId = $productId;
    }
}

class Cart
{
    private $cartId;

    public function addLine($productId, $price)
    {
        return new CartLine($this->cartId, $productId, $price);
    }
}

/**
 * Provides price for specific country
 */
class PriceProvider
{
    public function priceForProduct($productId, $userId, $country)
    {
        // Logic for determining product price for customer
        // Based on available global discounts, user discounts and country
    }
}

/**
 * Command for adding product to cart
 */
class AddProductToCart
{
    public $customerId;
    public $productId;
}

/**
 * An application service to bind everything together
 */
class CustomerService
{
    public function addProductToCart(AddProductToCart $command)
    {
        /** @var Customer $customer */
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->customerOfId($command->customerId);
        $cartLine = $customer->addProductToCart($command->productId);

        $this->cartLineRepository->save($cartLine);
    }
}
```

Is this a correct approach? Do I violate any DDD principles here? Can I improve something?

Comment: You need an event too: AddProductToCartCommand-->ProductAddedToCartEvent

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Is this intended to be a learning app or a production app ?

Comment: @Sudarshan, It might end up being small production one. ;)

Comment: Why do you ask? Should I change something?

Answer (score 1):

CQRS generally involves **command handler**.
Command is associated to "imperative" verb.
`CustomerService` is too broad and so does not represent the intent of the "command".

I would change `CustomerService` by `AddProductToCart`:

```
class AddProductToCart
{
    public function handle(AddProductToCartCommand $command) {
      ...
    }
}
```

By the way, by splitting all your various functionalities into appropriate commands, you would be able to make several versions of one specific command them if you need to.

Comment: You are right, I should have used a handler there. I'm assuming this handler should be a part of domain not app layer?

Comment: app layer, it s still like an app service

Comment: @acid You should read this: https://code.google.com/p/ddd-cqrs-sample/wiki/DomainDrivenDesignBusinessDeveloperMentalModel#Commands/Services  There's even a full example (in code) of CQRS dealing with command handlers.

Answer (score 0):

So in sparse order (and partially depending on the programming language):

- Your aggregate root should be explicitly marked (using an IAggregateRoot interface for example) so if your language supports generic, you can implement only repository of an aggregate root.
- Your constructors should be always private, use factory instead. Use constructor only for initialization issue. In your next future the building rule of a `Customer` could increase in complexity and factory will permit you flexibility.
- Invariant logic is Domain Logic. Logic that depends on use case is Application Logic (i.e. `PriceProvide`r is not related to domain logic)

Comment: How is determining which rules to apply to which product to determine its price not a domain logic? Maybe it shouldn't reside in this AR (but if not, then where?), but for me that's definitely a domain layer.